# SQL Insert with Select doesn't work

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL statement like that:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_3(TABLE_1ID, TABLE_2ID) 
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NAME = '..', 
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE NAME = '..';
```

But it doesn't work. I just get an error

> *Statement ... near "SELECT": syntax error.*

So how to do it correctly? There's no example how to handle this with two selects from two different tables.

This would work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1(NAME, AGE)
SELECT NAME, AGE FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ID = '..';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join the 2 tables, since I don't know your db structure, I am gonna assume that Name is the only common reference between the 2 tables, if that's not the case, and you actually have something more solid (like an actual foreign key) then you should use that.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_3
       (TABLE_1ID, TABLE_2ID) 
SELECT TABLE_1.ID, TABLE_2.ID 
FROM TABLE_1 
     JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.NAME = TABLE_2.NAME
WHERE TABLE_1.NAME = '..'
```

From your comment, it seems like there is no relation between TABLE_2 and TABLE_3, in which case, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_3
       (TABLE_1ID, TABLE_2ID) 
SELECT (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NAME = '..'), 
       (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE NAME = '..')
```

Comment: what's the relation between Table_1 and Table_2? just an id based on the name?

Comment: The relation between Table_1 and Table_2 is m:n. To handle this i want to have Table_3 with the ID of Talbe_1 and the ID of Table_2.

Comment: NAME is UNIQUE by the way, in both tables for this i use it as an identifiere to get the correct id